# Wix installer - Unable to delete Installation directory after uninstallation

Tags: wix, windows-installer, wix3.7

My installation directory contains multiple folders and files. The folders are with admin privileges. I am able to cleanup everything in Installation directory but installation directory itself remains.

Tried RemoveFolder and RemoveFolderEx utility but could not succeed.

Comment: Check for the component settings of install directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After so many attempts finally moved to c++ custom action where I have more control over files.

Solution:
Even after DeleteServices the service executable take time to exit. That was holding the log files. So I put while loop with 1 second sleep and kept checking the log files for deletion. After deleting those log files, also deleted the folder from same custom action.